# Battery made of Li-ion cells assembly

Tags: lithium-ion, safety, assembly, batteries

Do you see any issue (feasability, **safery**, ...) about assembling a battery pack with 10 [Li-ion 3.7V 2600mAh cells](https://www.exoindustry.fr/shop/product/p255170-4-x-packs-batterie-li-ion-1s1p-3-7v-2600mah-333#attr=) (put in parallel) having their own individual protection circuits (overcharge and over discharge voltages protection, over current protection) with this [module](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005002619314989.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=248-630-5778&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=10191220526&albag=107473525328&trgt=539263010115&crea=fr1005002619314989&netw=u&device=c&albpg=539263010115&albpd=fr1005002619314989&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnueFBhChARIsAPu3YkSCZEB-FIKQaZSpd7awZRjX4YiVguuxEUZ8PoyrCR8Ug0ay5TtybSoaAmSbEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) (charger, protections and 5V converter) ?

Note 1: the maximum discharging current specified for the cell is: 1000mA (wrongly specified at the given link)

Note 2: the 5V converter on the module is for power supplying the load.

My second question: how to make the more simple and safety assembly of the cells? They have wires, can I make simple connexion as splice between all positive wires (and also between all negative wires) by respecting same length of wires between the cells and the splice ?

Comment: You should provide links to the **manufacturer's datasheets** for the cells and for the BMS. A link to aliexpress, much less in French, is worthless.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have more information for BMS (this is aliexpress... !) but it already gives good information about protection and their thresholds. This is pretty the same on the cells. Sorry for french links ;), but btw, all internet explorer makes good english translate throught ;)

Comment: Be aware that the module you want use (... perhaps ...) have the two "usb" (+ and -) connected together, and in some converters, you can use the 2 USB ports as power input OR power output.

Comment: Assembly in parallel must be made with "same" model of batteries. The length of wires is "not very critical" ... exception with "high currents".

Comment: Don't use a BMS you got from aliexpress, get something reputable with an actual datasheet.

Comment: @Antonio51 thanks for this precision but here it says that micro USB port is for charging (from a power supply) and that USB port for the (regulated) output. For the same model of battery, yes, I do agree, it must be coming, if possible, from the same batch and they must be "balanced" before plugging. Thanks also for the wire advice but why do we then always see dot weldering using nickel tape and with no wire?

Comment: To be verifed ... because I was surprised for one "similar" component  :)   When you receive "sample", verify these connections.

Comment: For "spot welding" with nickel tape, no problem if batteries are same model and same "voltage" (be sure by measuring) before paralleling and welding ...  if you have a spot welder.

Comment: @Antonio51 true, I will check the behaviour of the module anyway as there is a lack of information on it o aliexpress.. Indeed, I don't have a spot welder and each cellule has already a Protection Circuit Module fixed at their top, with wires to connect the cellule. So I would like to know if it is OK to use all the celulle wires to make the system ? and how to make the connexion ?  (splice with classic welding, or terminal block connector for example)

Comment: Sorry, i close my "count" on this site